# Can I read an image into GD without knowing its type?

Tags: php, gd

GD seems to have various `imagecreatefrom_x_` functions which is great if you know the image type ahead of time. In my particular situation, I don't. Is there a way to read in the image without knowing the type?

My only option so far is to save it to disk (expensive!) and then use `getimagesize` (which also provides mime type) - but this results in me reading in the image twice - once to determine the MIME type and then again to read it into GD.

Alternatively, is it possible to just treat a variable as a file? something like this:

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://the.remote.file.com/myfile');

# doesn't work with already read in image ... can I treat this as a file w/o saving it?
$info = getimagesize($image);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring), which is indifferent to the actual file format and the best option if you've read in the file already.

But for practical purposes you should be able to use `getimagesize($filename)`. You don't have to read in the file before. Just use the filename or url.

```
print_r(
   getimagesize("http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=2")
);
```

Comment: yes but it fires off a request to the remote server to get the information; I need to cut down on the # of http requests being made over all. `imagecreatefromstring` looks promising however.

Comment: @Will: If it's a remote file, there is no way around transferring it first. The second access to the file is quite inexpensive in comparison, because it's also in the I/O cache. -- But again, use imagecreatefromstring() and the gd functions if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring), [imagesx](http://php.net/imagesx) and [imagesy](http://php.net/imagesy) (the latter two to prevent another request, since it seems to concern you):

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://path/to/image.jpg'));
list($width, $height) = array(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
```